# Find boundary points of a set of coordinates

Tags: python, boundary, roi

My objective is to get an ROI that is outlined in the black in image **The ideal result**.

After using the below Convex Hull Graham code, we are able to get an  ROI as shows in image **Result of the convex hull graham** (overlay in white). Convex Hull Graham is returning only the outter boundary points however, we need to our ROI to consider some intermediary points to give us a crisp shape.

```
def convex_hull_graham(points):

    TURN_LEFT, TURN_RIGHT, TURN_NONE = (1, -1, 0)

    def cmp(a, b):
        # return (a > b) - (a < b)
        return np.add((a<b), (a>b), dtype=np.float32)

    def turn(p, q, r):
        return cmp((q[0] - p[0])*(r[1] - p[1]) - (r[0] - p[0])*(q[1] - p[1]), 0)
    def _keep_left(hull, r):
        while len(hull) > 1 and turn(hull[-2], hull[-1], r) != TURN_LEFT:
            hull.pop()
        if not len(hull) or hull[-1] != r:
            hull.append(r)
        return hull
    points = list(points)
    points = [list(point) for point in points]

    points = sorted(points)
    l = reduce(_keep_left, points, [])
    u = reduce(_keep_left, reversed(points), [])

    return l.extend(u[i] for i in range(1, len(u) -1)) or l
```

We have tried several methods including Shapely, Nearest neighbors, KDTree but nothing has worked. Attached are the points in the image.
[Result of the convex hull graham](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X94ah.png)

[The ideal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daRCn.png)

This is the link for the points (.npy file)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CWWOWVgELPXBAG25barpbtWyvBV8WHGG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549128/boundary-enclosing-a-given-set-of-points answer your question?

Comment: I have tried that one too. But I'm unable to draw the edges properly